NullPointerException error in GA algorithm- An agent-based supply chain model
I am trying to use Genetic Algorithm to optimize my agent-base model in anylogic. However, I got this error: NullPointerException. It seems my model cannot read the objective function, which is the total coat.
I am trying to use Genetic Algorithm to optimize my agent-base model in the field of supply chain management. However, I got this error: NullPointerException. It seems my model cannot read the objective function, which is the total coat. On the other hand, I tried Optquest as well and learned that it works. my problem has 22 decision variables which are related to the order-up-to level inventory policy. I want to the get the optimal values for minimum and maximum inventory levels related to this policy, while cost is minimized. I would appreciate it if you could guide me what the problem is and how I can fix it. Thanks!

Can you add your code?

I used this code to refer my objective function: root.totalCostSupplyChainNew. and I defined my decision variables in parameters section.

Hey, pls think about how you present your question and if it would even be possible  to help with what you provide. In this case: no. Add code, screenshots, make it easy for us to help you. Some tips to improve: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

oh, and it suffices to use the anylogic tag only ;)

Thanks for your points. So is it possible to help me resolve this error? I just simply used this code " root.totalCostSupplyChainNew" to call my objective function that I want to minimize it. But I am getting this error: NullPointerException
